# ASP.NET Data Annotations: How to share with a JSON client?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

We have two data models: read only View Models going to the client and "Control" Models sending modified data back.  Essentially, they are the same, and all have Data Annotations like this on them:

```
// Require nothing but one or more digits
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+$", ErrorMessage = "*")]
public string productid {get;set;}
```

All of our communication goes through Controller Methods using `JsonResult` and `Json()`.

**How could the client honor these data annotations?**  Specifically, how could a JQuery plugin like validate receive these regular expressions, required, ranges, etc. to use for itself?

We have a response that includes a header object with nested collections (like a product list List).  We were thinking the Regex could exist in the header, then applied to all the form fields.  **But how could we translate the annotations to a JSON serialized object?**

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/08/23/asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-and-validationsummary.aspx) blog post.

Essentially you call an MVC Html Helper method `<% Html.EnableClientValidation();%>` that outputs some JSON onto the page. Then there is a translation method in the `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js` that feeds jquery validate with the data annotations for each field.

---

**Update for comments**

If you are rendering the `HTMLFormElements` without using mvc controls it will be much more difficult. You will probably need to look at the `ViewData.ModelMetadata` to access the data annotations. Possibly need to use a custom MetaDataProvider I would consider going to MVC3 RC so I could use th unobtrusive validation (data attribute)

Here are some links:

- [Brad Wilson: Unobtrusive Client Validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)
- [Brad Wilson: Model Metadata](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html)

Comment: what if you never make it to the view, i.e., no aspx page?

Comment: @Dr. Zim - Not sure I understand your question. Do you want to validate data against a data annotated model, or get the data annotations in json? Client validation implies user input - without ever "making it" to a view I can't see how that is possible.

Comment: We use JQuery Ajax calls to bring data to the client, then use Microsoft JQuery templates to render content, and use Microsoft data linking to bind an array to the form elements.  Somehow, I need to translate the Regex attached to the classes to something that JQuery validate plugin can use (for example).

Comment: So i'm guessing you are not using the mvc html helpers - ValidateFor/TextboxFor etc?

Comment: Nope.  I am using ModelState.IsValid() on the JSON return objects, which works very well.  Just wondering how to share these data annotations with JQuery Validate by sending JSON directly to the client.